# Why does dotnet build not include folders when running release?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to build a .net core 3 Web App in release mode, but the folders wwwroot and ClientApp are missing from the published source.

I tried adding them manually to the .csproj like below, and the folders get included but none of the content in them.

Any ideas?

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="ClientApp\*" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `**` wildcard to include everything in these folders. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2019#use-wildcards-to-specify-items) states:

> The ** wildcard character sequence matches a partial path.

So your ItemGroup would look like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="ClientApp\**" />
  <None Include="wwwroot\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```